# Find position of the first occurence of a substring in a file

Tags: shell, file, unix

I have a very large file, which is made of only one line (no CR at all). 
I have several occurences of the same pattern (let's say here , the pattern is `ABCDE`). 
I want to return the starting position or the starting column of the first character of the first occurence of this pattern...

for example, if this is the data in the file :

```
123456ABCDEF456987ABCDEFjhkhkhkhABCDEF
```

I want to return 7 as the starting column of the first occurence of the pattern...

thanks community :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use awk `index()` function:

```
awk -v pattern="ABCDE" '{print index($0,pattern)}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the "C" option of "split", so there will be no need to repair the files afterwards.

```
   -C, --line-bytes=SIZE
          put at most SIZE bytes of lines per output file
```